# How to display only every Nth element on a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

Let's say I would like to display the results of a sequence:

```
plot(runif(10,0,1), type="o")
```

in a way to display all of the elements with a connected line **but** plot the corresponding icons (circles/diamonds/etc.) assigned with `pch` only for every second, third, or Nth element?

Should I create two sequence, one with filtered elements and display it as a different `line()`? Isn't there a bit elegant way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just mean something like this `plot(runif(10,0,1), type="o", pch=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3))` but with a specified sequence?

Comment: In your case probably that would be `plot(runif(10, 0, 1), type = "o", pch = c(20, rep(NA, 3)))` for every 4th element.

Comment: @Julius Great, that was exactly what I was searching for, thx! Can you submit it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case probably that would be

```
plot(runif(10, 0, 1), type = "o", pch = c(20, rep(NA, 3)))
```

for lets say every 4th element.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just add the `pch` argument to `plot` with whatever sequence you are looking for: For example:

```
set.seed(1)
# I've used 'type="b"' just for clarity
plot(runif(10, 0, 1), 
     type="b", 
     pch=rep(c(1, 2, 3), length.out=10))
```

will give you this:

[image]